# HP LaserJet 1020 always asks for driver install

Tags: drivers, python, printing

On Ubuntu 10.10, HP LaserJet 1020 works plug and play style (plugged it in, printed test page without installing anything). But, every time I connect (or power on ubuntu) printer starts it's driver install console, offering to download drivers/install existing/quit install. I've tried downloading but it fails with some python error.

Is there way to disable this driver install? Or at least work around this python error so that install can pass...

Screenshot of error:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I get the same popup, but no errors. Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope, still an issue :((

Comment: Reported the bug - subscribe to it and maybe it solves your issue too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/780983

Comment: Hit the link and click "it affects me too" and maybe we'll get some of the Ubuntu Pros to look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has resolved itself today. Driver downloaded and installed itself without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

@Vnuk: I have the same printer and went through the same problem.  Run the utility with sudo rights from the console:

```
sudo hp-plugin-ubuntu
```

That way it will download and install the plugin without issues.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm updating my question with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this week (CW1 2012) the download server is down again and hplip is unable to load the firmware.
I've used foo2zjs, look here for a description how to: https://plus.google.com/u/0/112161258221779145276/posts/imgVhbXxRWC